# Рассиномизировать angular и angularjs

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Под [angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) подразумевается фреймворк, который возник в версии 2.0 и уже вышла бета шестой версии. Под [angularjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) подразумевается фреймворк, у которого сейчас последняя версия 1.6.6 и у него всегда будет версия 1.x. И они развивались всегда и развиваются как разные продукты.

Кто не в теме поясню: это не просто версии одного и того же продукта, это совершенно разные фреймворки от тех же создателей, просто со схожими названиями. Там отличий просто немеряно, а вот сходств почти не найдёте. То есть с таким же успехом можно синонимизировать [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) и [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) и [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) и т.д., просто потому что названия похожи, синтаксис и пару базовых концепеций. И я не преувеличиваю. Это настолько же абсурдно, как эти синонимы.

### Результаты

Метки рассинонимизировали, но теперь на [angularjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) все вопросы (1396 на момент написания), а на [angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) — 0.

Про то, как сделать, чтобы вернуть метки "как было" написал [вопрос на главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308360/346987) и [Николасу в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43612007#43612007). Может поможет.

<strike>**Update пока писал**: ответили на главной мете, что метки смёржили (а не синонимизировали) и это необратимо. Неужели, это правда и это произошло даже без дискуссии на мете (по крайней мере, не нашёл)?</strike>

Всё выяснилось: [синоним существовал с января 2016го года](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/830740)! Поэтому можно уже не париться.

Comment: Удалил синоним.

Comment: Не уверен, какой тег должен остаться на существующих вопросах. Сейчас оставлен angular, стоит пройтись по недавним вопросам и проставить angularjs по необходимости

Comment: А если ли возможность сделать это намного тоньше: узнать какие из вопросов были с меткой [tag:angular] и сделать чтобы на них она и осталась? То есть вернуть состояние до синонимизации. Это ошибочная синонимизация поломала метки **возможно** (я не уверен, и даже без понятия как это можно подсчитать без Николаса), сотен вопросов. И вручную это править очень долго и ненадёжно.

Comment: встроенными средствами сайта - нельзя. попробуйте покопать SEDE.

Comment: @PashaPash, а почему в [tag:angularjs] теперь нет вопросов?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что у всех вопросов был [tag:angularjs]. Я разорвал синоним с заменой на [tag:angular] как более старый (и, наверное, более распространненный)

Comment: @PashaPash, наоборот, [tag:angularjs] - это старый, а [tag:angular] скорее всего идёт на сайте как [tag:angular2] и другие с версиями.

Comment: @PashaPash Это точно зря, [tag:angularjs] более старый и намного более спрашиваемый. Даже на enSO по [tag:angularjs] в 2,5 раза больше вопросов. У нас плюс-минус то же самое.

Comment: ок, переименовал назад

Comment: Разделить необходимо. Но в метках надо указать отличие. Старые вопросы просто не сортировать. Или ждать добровольцев.

Comment: Можно все–таки часть наиболее важных вопросов перенести на правильную метку. Если нет вопросов по метке, то нет и метки. Также хотелось бы иметь правильную выборку вопросов по каждой из меток в будущем, это поможет поддерживать базу знаний в актуальном состоянии.

Comment: @PashaPash А можете, пожалуйста, добавить [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А можете, пожалуйста, добавить [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Да, конечно! Спасибо за напоминание!

Answer (score 1):

Вопросы для проверки на принадлежность новому ангуляру:
http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/830609/1024697/angularjs-that-can-be-angular

```
select
  Id, CreationDate, Title, Body, Tags
from
  Posts
where
  Tags like N'%<angularjs>%'
  and PostTypeId = 1
  and not Tags like N'%<angularjs-%>%'
  and not LOWER(Title) like N'%angularjs%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%angularjs%'
  and not LOWER(Title) like N'%angular js%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%angular js%'
  and not LOWER(Title) like N'%$scope%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%$scope%'
  and not LOWER(Title) like N'%ng-repeat%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%ng-repeat%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%ng-if%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%ng-show%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%ng-hide%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%ng-src%'
  and not LOWER(Title) like N'%ui-router%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%ui-router%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%digest%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%$http%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%$filter%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%$rootScope%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%.controller%'
  and not LOWER(Body)  like N'%.module%'
order by
  CreationDate desc
```

Получилось 342 (или 334) вопроса:

[При обращении к массиву внутри $rootScope выдает undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803894)
[Переменные в глобальных стилях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/800956)
[Angular динамическое обновление на телефоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/800759)
[Какой веб-сервер поднять при использовании Angular+Postgress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/798616)
[Chart js. Как переделать код с jquery на angular, чтобы передать данные для построения графиков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/794570)
[Angular2 + .net core не работает webpack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/791995)
[Оповещения spring angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790965)
[Как поменять название кнопки (Submit), которая генерируется автоматически ангуляром](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/788281)
[Наследование Angular 2 и Typescript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786965)
[Angular 5 *ngIf параметры из запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785455)
[Node js + angular 1.6 routing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784896)
[Не могу получить заголовки объекта Response](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784620)
[Как мне разобрать данные через ngFor Angular c разными условиями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/783444)
[Изменение ширины директивы в зависимости от контента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782746)
[Как работает передача параметров в post методе с# ASP.NET Core angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/781314)
[Умножение значения слайдера на число jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/780300)
[Angular,основы Как это работает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778811)
[Загрузить HTML из файла в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778101)
[Формат даты отправленный из Angular в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775914)
[Vuejs пустая и заполненная форма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775749)
[Как реализовать сортировку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774968)
[Angular2. Не запускается метод в app.component.ts](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774526)
[Ошибка приложения Angular 5 на браузере IE 11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774404)
[JavaScript без быдлокодинга](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774212)
[Не работает Data Binding в Ionic, Angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/773456)
[Как правильно собрать проект angular-cli?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/773149)
[Логирование данных из ng-bind](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/773132)
[Как лучше хранить сообщения чата?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/771610)
[Как правильно сформировать JSON для ASP контроллера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768254)
[Неизвестная ошибка в Angular Universal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767776)
[Массив не инициализируется в сервисе Angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/766966)
[Проблема переподписки на другой странице Angular 5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/765267)
[символ @ в пакетах npm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764960)
[Cannot find control with name: 'rest_solution'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/763795)
[Angular 2 +ASP.NET CORE 2 + JWT AUTH TOKEN : ERROR:415 Unsuported media Type](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/763148)
[В $onDestroy отменить destroy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/761372)
[Angular 5 Как подключить директиву?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759447)
[angular как сделать include html в другой html файл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759300)
[Анимация кнопки в angular 4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759102)
[Angular Material 5 не работает Sidenav](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/757562)
[Перевести числа в денежный формат (1 000, 10 000 и т.д.)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/757281)
[Как убрать лишнее поле в объекте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756005)
[Помогите разобраться с теорией по Angular (React, Vue)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/754166)
[Не удаляется документ из коллекции бд MongoDB](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/744722)
[Получить массив обьектов из Json в Angular 4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/744404)
[Как тестировать angular 1 компоненты при апгрейде до angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743960)
[Запуск сетевого сервера для разработки проекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743714)
[Как разместить элементы header горизонтально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739366)
[Редирект на сайт на Angular с POST данными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737911)
[Как правильно работать с SASS (BEM) в Angular 4?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734374)
[Не отображается русский язык в asp.net core + angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731728)
[Будут ли конфликты между ангуляровским роутем и реактовским?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729758)
[Как получить список фильмов imdb api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729386)
[Как выделить, сохранить выделение, и восстановить его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728973)
[Передача данных с Front-end [Angular 4] на Back-end [NodeJS]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728464)
[Как отменить анимацию когда input пустой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728060)
[Что такое ngx-bootstrap?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/727410)
[Последовательность действий при использовании директив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726480)
[Представление таблиц идентичных значений по условию Angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722862)
[Как в Angular сделать переход между страницами без перезагрузки и без # в адресной строке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/720058)
[Скрабер ведет себя ненормально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/718666)
[Фильтрация JSON объектов Angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/718527)
[Не подключается сервис Angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717564)
[оптимизация сборки webpack & angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717420)
[Почему не работает роутинг в Angular 2?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716986)
[Передача методов через postmessage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716056)
[Как отменить фокус](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714978)
[Есть приложение на IONIC. Как сделать условие?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/713564)
[проверить навешано ли событие на элемент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/712294)
[Как добраться до ангулярных данных, привязанных к элементу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709578)
[WEB components и Angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706592)
[Корзина angular.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706561)
[Вертикальное положение таблицы ng2-table angular2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706344)
[Проверка, что пользователь не отправляет время раньше текущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706006)
[Как вернуть с сервера сообщение об ошибке с русским текстом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/703298)
[Распарсить XML SCG и вывести ан страницу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702057)
[Как выделить первую строку по умолчанию в компоненте AgGrid?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701514)
[Проблемы с навигацией в ag-grid-angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700778)
[Не отображать в url предыдущий state или поменять states местами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700565)
[Локальный кэш веб-приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700051)
[Навигация по компонент DataTable из PrimeNG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700022)
[Yandex maps в angular 4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/695153)
[Закэшировать или преобразовать в картинку и опять закэшировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694159)
[window.onbeforeunload перестал работать при подключении angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694022)
[Проблемы с скроллингом при наличии слайдера на странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693032)
[Стоит ли использовать Angular.js при создании динамичного приложения (без перезагрузки страницы) на node.js?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692857)
[Внесение в диаграмму Google значения ng-model](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692541)
[Как задать класс стиля в компоненте PrimeNG?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/691872)
[Не работает валидация md-autocomplete Angular2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690884)
[Нарисовать граф](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690503)
[angular динамическое добавление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/687954)
[Привязка данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/687573)
[как получить чистый url в ангулар-cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685078)
[Angular 2 POST request to the server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684637)
[Как использовать большое количество шаблонов в Angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/681367)
[angular routing - возможна ли реализация подстраниц?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/679523)
[Restangular, не приходят данные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678528)
[Как передать данные объекта между событиями ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/677399)
[Заголовок OPTIONS при авторизации через JWT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675997)
[Как добавить префикс к url в Angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675396)
[Перезагрузка компонента Angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/674174)
[Видоизменение объекта при отправке на сервер Restangular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/672514)
[Как завести участок кода jQuery (if \ else)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/671267)
[Разрабока angular+yi2 на локальной машине без кросс-доменных запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670927)
[Как заставить $routeProvider игнорировать ссылки с заглушками "#"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/666907)
[Angular 2-4 перезагрузить теплейт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/664547)
[Как на карту leaflet засунуть select используя angular-leaflet-directive?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/664396)
[Неправильное формирование заголовка http-запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/663574)
[Добавление тегов на сайт, возможно при помощи радио баттонов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/663068)
[Немогу избавится от пустого option (Angular)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662975)
[Carousel (Angular 2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/661372)
[Как создать модуль Angular 2 на es6 без typeScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/660125)
[Проблема с запросом get в Angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/660037)
[Как правильно внедрить в сайт на angular1 код RTB (Рекламная сеть Яндекс)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/658905)
[Картинка прогружается только на половину экрана](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/656559)
[Angular2 PrimeNG, не работает ng-template](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/656480)
[Запретить ввод основания натурального логарифма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/656221)
[Как заставить Dart with angular2 работать в разных браузерах?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654607)
[Не работает динамический ng-click](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/653766)
[Как сделать автоматический отступ когда категория раскрывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/652985)
[Nginx rewrite для GoogleBot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/652701)
[Ошибка при POST из Angular в Flask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/652642)
[Как правильно собирать проект на Angular2?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/649796)
[Как сохранять данные в LocalStorage при переполнении памяти в 5мб?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647287)
[Как остановить кэширование controller.js в Angular?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646499)
[Проблемы с установкой Java bridge for JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/645770)
[$location.path() в safari](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/645621)
[Не запускается angular-fullstack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/645318)
[Как организовать работу скрипта на другом ресурсе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/645175)
[Как сэмулировать действие spin buttons?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/640233)
[Angular 2 и DOM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/639406)
[Какая технология используется?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/638153)
[Можно ли индексировать веб-приложение на Angular 2 поисковыми ботами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/635065)
[Angular 2 и внешний JS-скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/634932)
[Angular 2 и MS SQL Server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/631768)
[Как определить, что поле формы сейчас редактируется (js/php)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628648)
[Белый экран при запуске приложения на Ionic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626107)
[Angular2 после обновления страницы возвращает 404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624237)
[Angular запускает функцию fireUrlChange()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624092)
[Проблема с кареткой в angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/622842)
[Переход по страницам в Ionic-приложении (Routing)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/622436)
[Не работает тестовый пример Angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618827)
[Событие change не обрабатывает изменения в input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616658)
[Как сделать кнопку с функциональностью ссылки (html)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615784)
[Обращение к родителю из router outlet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615610)
[Стоит ли использовать Angular 1?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/614834)
[Angular2 загрузка стилей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/614029)
[Angular 2 показ меню по клику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/613365)
[Как в angular tranlate узнать текущий язык?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/613324)
[числовой параметр в ng-model превращает текстовое поле ввода в числовое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612946)
[Не срабатывает break в JS коде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612910)
[Как в angular-google-maps запретить перетаскивать выше и ниже карты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608578)
[angular 1.5 translate переводит в &#1058;&#1072;](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606187)
[Как организовать постепенную загрузку данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/605672)
[Работа с датой в JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/603832)
[Есть ли возможность в angular выводить данные через pattern?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/603128)
[Оптимизация работы Angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/601035)
[Зачем нужен Angular.js?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599168)
[Controllers и factory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/598264)
[Динамический роутер с проверкой через сервис](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597334)
[Angular vs jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596761)
[Как предотвратить вывод ошибок по throw внутри секций then библиотеки Promise Q?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596203)
[Как правильно отрефакторить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595480)
[Как организовать правку модели с возможностью применить/отменить изменения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594929)
[Не работает ответ от запроса, отправленного Ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594393)
[удаление и запись обьектов в json файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594130)
[Не удается загрузить картинку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/593443)
[Nodejs + angular, как правильно организовать разработку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592733)
[Как ограничить доступ ко всей админке? JwT Laravel Angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/591301)
[Angular routing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590085)
[Шрифты отображаются не всегда корректно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/589391)
[В чём различие в способах передачи атрибута в директиву?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587806)
[Какой стек выбрать для SPA и десктопного приложения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/586485)
[Laravel 5.3 на хосте(Centos 6.7)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/586450)
[Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 3 of the expression [{{book.rating}} > 0 && {{book.rating}} <= 5]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585568)
[ui-options и инцилизация параметров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/584158)
[md-select get selected value](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577898)
[Какую технологию использовать для простой доски объявлений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576763)
[Как найти количество и позицию символа в строке (javascript)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576555)
[Работа с socket.io в angular 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576198)
[Angular form сбросить значения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575996)
[Передача данных в Angular2 через Inputs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575745)
[вылезает ui-select, при выборе, за границы ячейки таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571907)
[Как сделать, чтобы фильтр в Angular включался по checkbox и по нему же отключался?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571051)
[Добавить скролл блоку, который не влазит целиком на страницу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/569637)
[multiple select установить фокус](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568886)
[Как отловить событие перехода на сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568873)
[Как подключить сервис $mdToast c Angular Material в TypeScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565923)
[Angular html input'ы с общим значением max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563920)
[Ionic JSON локально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563657)
[Динамически изменить script src в Angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563174)
[Шаблонизация в веб приложениях: сервер, клиент, смешанная?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562838)
[Можно ли добавить поддержку Angular в PhpStorm?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562748)
[Как правильно использовать promise в моем случае?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/560035)
[Обработка изображения в ionic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/558710)
[Phalcon + Angular. Не работает [ngRoute]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/557680)
[ng-model убирает отображение стандартного value из input'a, помогите поправить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/557508)
[XMLHttpRequest cannot load к laravel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554772)
[Помогите продумать архитектуру приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/553557)
[Как сделать роутинг с ui route из ссылки выпадающего списка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549080)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547389
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547240
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/544708
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/544397
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543276
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541920
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541747
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540679
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540028
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538272
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536660
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536601
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533711
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/530331
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521122
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520148
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519342
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518639
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518361
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517676
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516631
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516619
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514994
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514942
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512598
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510882
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510411
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509857
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509618
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509107
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/508785
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/508453
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507857
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507494
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507243
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505558
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503630
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500364
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498585
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497920
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497378
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497177
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496209
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495324
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/493723
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490554
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489446
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489096
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487958
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487762
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487501
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487491
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487432
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487284
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486176
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484860
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481200
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480319
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479232
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478939
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478809
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478624
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478155
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478087
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476962
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476062
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475462
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475277
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474644
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/473659
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/473067
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/473006
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472805
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472691
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472076
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470142
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468046
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467529
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467443
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/462676
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/462582
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460431
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459308
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457662
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455374
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455033
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454601
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454574
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454497
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454139
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453035
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/452497
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/452487
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450704
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450559
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450407
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448198
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445721
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445599
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444788
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444443
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438449
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435790
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435653
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434602
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434502
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429916
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427729
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427574
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426518
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423831
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/422221
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420119
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418447
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417943
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417303
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416229
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414938
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/410168
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/408037
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/402636
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/402164
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/401558
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/390764
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372090
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/371964
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/362975
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/361507
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/361059
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/358008
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/352859
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/349832
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/332914
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/285433

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308355/309650

Comment: Спасибо за старания, только я не уверен, насколько это надёжно попытаться определять принадлежность постов по таким косвенным признакам как отсутствие синтаксических конструкций angularjs.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, если конструкции есть, то и первый ангуляр в вопорсе есть. Конечно, может быть вопрос по обоим ангулярам, но это пока отложим.

Comment: Есть ещё надёжная идея: найти дату самой первого публичного релиза ангуляра 2 и это будет ещё один из критериев фильтрации. Главное, дату узнать наверняка. Если я правильно делаю выводы из [англ. википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(application_platform)): "On April 30, 2015, the Angular developers announced that Angular 2 moved from Alpha to Developer Preview". Но я в этом не уверен. Может альфа там тоже публичной была. Я не настолько плотно сидел на нём.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, список отсортирован по убыванию даты.

Comment: [Оказалось, синоним существовал с января 2016 года](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/830740).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, первый вопросы в отобранном списке были явно с неверными метками.